# More CakePHP Email Component Troubles

Tags: email, cakephp

I recently [posted a question about the CakePHP email component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006312/how-do-i-use-the-cakephp-email-component/), and, with the help of some of the answers and comments, was able to resolve my problem...

The thing is, solving my email problem revealed another problem!

So, here's my problem:

I have a contract that has a client associated with it. When I create a contract, I select a client. I want to send an email to the client with a link to the contract when I save the contract to the database. However, when I save the contract, no email gets sent! I know that the email is working. If I actually hardcode all of the variables, everything works. But, when I try to dynamically retrieve client info from the database, it doesn't work.

I did see a solution that involved the getByLastId(), but I don't think that will work in this case, because I don't need the most recently added user...I need the user who is attached to this contract.

I hope I am explaining this well.

Here is the code that I think is pertinent...if you need more info, let me know and I'll post it.

Here is the code in my contracts_controller.php for my email sending function:

```
    function _sendContractEmail($id) {
     $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
  'port'=>'587',
  'timeout'=>'30',
  'host'=>'smtp.email.com',
  'username'=>'username',
  'password'=>'password'
     );
     $User = $this->Contract->User->read(null,$id);
     $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
     $this->Email->to = $User['User']['email'];
     $this->Email->subject = 'New Contract from Company';
     $this->Email->replyTo = 'noreply@example.com';
     $this->Email->from = 'noreply@example.com';
     $this->Email->template = 'default';
     $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
     $this->set('User', $User);
     $this->Email->send('Test');
     $this->set('smtp-errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
 }
```

And here is the code in my contracts_controller.php for the add() function:

```
    function add() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
   $this->Contract->create();
   if ($this->Contract->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Contract has been saved', true));
    $this->_sendContractEmail($this->Contract->User->id);
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Contract could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
   }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jeremiah

Comment: This looks at first glance like it will work.  What output do you get?  Any errors from Email::smtpError?  Do you have the correct login info for SMTP setup somewhere?  Is $this->Contract->User->id set properly?  What does your $User look like?

Comment: Actually, I'm relatively new to PHP...how would I see what $User looks like? I'm guessing I could use debug($User); but where would I actually put that? And, I didn't realize that I needed to set $this->Contract->User->id, since it's a parameter. As far as the SMTP goes, I know that everything works perfectly...because when I change  $this->Email->to = "email@example.com" I actually get the email. It's when I try to grab it out of $User['User']['email'] it stops working. That's why I think the problem is not the SMTP settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findBy<fieldName>(string $value)` ( $this->Contact->User->findById($id) )

http://book.cakephp.org/view/451/findBy

This method can return multiple values so use pr($User) to see the array format. You should be able to find the user details in $User[0]['User']['email'].

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post this as comment because I'm not sure if this will work, but I don't have enough reputation to make comments yet :p

Have you tried this?

```
var $uses = array('User');
$user = $this->User->read(null,$id);
```

or

```
$user = $this->User->findById($id)
```